# git submodule not pushing into correct repo

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a repo where I'm developing some library and I generate the /dist folder that I want then to push into another repo so that other apps can import only this.

So I read that adding this /dist as a submodule would be a way to do that.

My main folder (with my /src, package.json and so on) has a remote like this:

```
MINGW64 ~/Documents/myapp-dw (master)
$ git remote -v
origin  https://.../_git/myapp-dw (fetch)
origin  https://.../_git/myapp-dw (push)
```

now I add a submodule with

```
$ git submodule add https://.../_git/myapp-dw-dist dist
```

and a new .modules file is created with the information for the new module.

Next, I generate my dist folder with an npm task and the folder is created with the rest of the files inside.

I do `git status` and I see that folder /dist has been modified.

So I go to /dist and I run `git add .` and `git commit`

Next I do `git push` from my main folder and the /dist folder is pushed into my main repository instead of my dist repository.

What am I missing here? I thought this was supposed to go into myapp-dw-dist as I added it as a different submodule.

EDIT: Just in case, I have to say that every time I rebuild my /dist folder I'm removing the folder completely (rimraf) and create it again... is it possible I'm removing some sensitive git information? I was under the impression that all git needed was the .modules file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After calling `$ git submodule add https://.../_git/myapp-dw-dist dist`, there should already exist a new folder `dist`. Everything that happens in this folder (and only things happening in this folder) will be pushed to the `myapp-dw-dist` repository.

You may, however, not have noticed the directory since it will be empty until you run `$ git submodule init`. This should make all the files from your `myapp-dw-dist` repo appear inside. Changes inside the folder can now be committed an pushed *from within this folder (i.e. repository)*.

After committing changes in the submodule, do not forget to commit the changed state of your submodule in the parent repository.

For more documentation on submodules, see [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

EDIT: Ah, there's the problem! As you say in your edit, when you delete the `dist` folder, you also delete the `dist/.git` folder. That is the folder telling git into which repository to push. As long as there's no `.git` folder in your submodule, git will think it's just another folder in your parent repository and push where everything else gets pushed.

You could either try to only delete the files inside `dist` instead of the whole folder, or re-add the submodule after every change (which does sound somewhat more error-prone).